# What is best practice for deleting respective data into another tables. Mysql delete query OR mysql Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

Mysql Delete query VS Mysql Triggers (which is fast option?)

Comment: This is like asking which is better, Coke or unicorns?  They are different things.

Comment: I know of very little requirements to use a delete statement in a trigger. Kinda dangerous if you ask me

Comment: My concern is i 've one users table and another tables with "userId" foreigner key. After delete any user m using trigger that delete all the entries respectivaly from another tables m not using one by one through PHP code. I want to know which is fast.

Comment: Agree with @BrianRamsey Delete in Trigger is dangerous, instead one can use cascade delete if required!

Comment: +1 cascade... though you're better off writing your deletes to remove the constraint values before the primary. Far better control

Comment: You people scaring me about Triggers :) and Yes you are right many people are preferring cascade Delete.
Thanks for this information.

Comment: If you have additional information which may be pertinent to the question, then EDIT THE QUESTION!!

Answer (score 1):

- Triggers if you want your DBA to be in control of the code.
- Query if you want your programmers to be in control of the code.

To clarify:

If it's a trigger, then the implication is that it's part of the database design for things to work that way. i.e. the structure of the database depends on it working that way.

If it's query code, then the implication is that the action is part of your business logic, and not critical to the core structure of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, they are different things. From MSDN: "A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server"; whereas a DELETE is a DML statement, that is, statement to manipulate database records. In this case, used for removing database records from a table or view.